# How to list installed Kubernetes operators, and delete them, via kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I use `kubectl` to list all the installed operators in my cluster? For instance running:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactive-tech/kubegres/v1.9/kubegres.yaml
```

installs the **Kubegres** (Postgres cluster provider) operator, but then how do I actually see that in a list of operators. Equally important to that, how do I uninstall the operator from my cluster via `kubectl`, or is that not possible to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless you are using [OLM](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-lifecycle-manager) to manage operator, there is no universal way to get rid of it.

Some operator might be installed using [Helm](https://helm.sh), then it's just matter of `helm delete ...`

You can always try to remove it using

```
kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactive-tech/kubegres/v1.9/kubegres.yaml
```

Generally speaking, to remove something, use same tool that you used for installation.

Comment: Thanks @rkosegi (+1) - do you see evidence of some kind of "delete hook" in that Kubegres YAML file, or does Kubernetes know to scan that YAML (when I specify `delete`) and jut undo all the resources contained therein?

Comment: when you do `delete` kubectl will read YAML file and perform delete against API server. YAML already contains everything necessary